# Redux middleware, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, observable

Hi i have a problem with fetching data by middleware in redux.
this is my MW:

```
export const tokenMiddleware = store => next => action => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'NEAR_YOU.FETCH':
          const { getState, dispatch } = store;
          console.log("NEAR_YOU.FETCH", action);
          dispatch({
            type: 'RESET_TOKEN',
            method: 'post'
          });
        break;
      default:
        console.log("default");
        next(action)
    }
};
```

and my epic:

```
export const resetTokenFetchEpic: Epic = createNamedEpic({
  actionID: 'RESET_TOKEN',
  endpoint: '/Api/v1/resetToken',
  callback: xxx => {
    console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", xxx);
  },
});
```

and i always get this error: 
[image]